# Adding Legend to plot in R

Tags: r, time-series

Hi I wish to create a legend for the following lines, but I am unsure how to.

```
lines1<- lines(salesARIMAPredict$pred, lty = 5, col = "Blue")
lines(salesARIMAPredict$pred+2*salesARIMAPredict$se, col = "Red") #Confidence Interval of 95%
lines(salesARIMAPredict$pred-2*salesARIMAPredict$se, col = "Red")
```

[See Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYNeA.png)

Many Thanks Saif

Comment: Format code lines in your posts by indenting it with four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You should do some basic research before asking questions: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/legend.html

Edit:

For you I created this simple example:

```
ts.plot(ldeaths)
lines(ldeaths+100, col ="red")
legend("top", c("ldeaths", "+100"), col = c("black", "red"), lty = 1)
```

Comment: ["Links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)